# Foreach with pass-by-reference gives different result than pass-by-value

Tags: php, foreach, pass-by-reference

I wrote a few lines of code in PHP to rename duplicate values in an array (with some inspiration [from here](http://geeksandgod.com/forums/web-development/php-/-mysql/find-duplicates-array)).
Basically, I go through the original array ($headers[]), while using the keys of another array ($header_test[]) to keep track of duplicates.  If there is a duplicate, I change the value of that element in $headers[].

But the weird thing is that I was not getting the right results by passing by reference in the foreach. I had to actually set the values by using the full $array_name[$key] = $new_value format.  Why is that?

(Spoiler alert: VolkerK's answer is correct - need to unset $header (the foreach "$value" variable) and then it works.)

Here:

Using this input:

```
$headers = array('Abc 123 ghi',
            'dangdarn',
            'oops32',
            'poss dup',
            'poss dup',
            'pos  _s_ dup',
            'bad chars\'& 3% 9'
           );
```

Then applying this custom function which I don't think would affect the problem at hand:

```
    function mysql_clean_string($string) {
    //remove non alnum characters
    $string =  preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "_", $string);

    // replace 1+ spaces or 1+ '_' with a single '_'
    $string =  preg_replace("/[ _]+/", "_", $string);

    $string = trim($string,'_');

    if(strlen($string) > 20) {
        $string = substr_replace($string,'',strpos($string,'_',20));
    }

    $string = strtolower($string);

    return $string;
}

array_walk($headers,'mysql_clean_string'); // limit headers to alnum chars
```

Passing the array values by reference doesn't work right (see below for var_dump()):

```
    $header_test = array();
    foreach($headers as &$header) { //passing by reference
        $temp = $header;
        if(array_key_exists($temp,$header_test)) {

            **$header = $header . '_' . $header_test[$header];**
            $header_test[$temp]++; 
            unset($temp);
        } else {
            $header_test[$temp] = 1;
        }
    }

//here is the solution VolkerK suggested and it works:
unset($header);
```

Here are the var_dump outputs with incorrect results (duplicate values and notice "&" at headers[6], and missing last value):

```
  ["headers"]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "abc_123_ghi"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "dangdarn"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "oops32"
    [3]=>
    **string(8) "poss_dup"**
    [4]=>
    string(10) "poss_dup_1"
    [5]=>
    string(9) "pos_s_dup"
    [6]=>
    **&string(8) "poss_dup"**
  }
  ["header_test"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["abc_123_ghi"]=>
    int(1)
    ["dangdarn"]=>
    int(1)
    ["oops32"]=>
    int(1)
    ["poss_dup"]=>
    int(2)
    ["pos_s_dup"]=>
    int(1)
    ["bad_chars_3_9"]=>
    int(1)
  }
```

And now here is what works, which is to use $original_array[$key] = $new_value format:

```
$header_test = array();
foreach($headers as $key => $header) {
    $temp = $header;
    if(array_key_exists($temp,$header_test)) {

        **$headers[$key] = $header . '_' . $header_test[$header];**
        $header_test[$temp]++; 
        unset($temp);
    } else {
        $header_test[$temp] = 1;
    }
}
```

var_dump:

```
  ["headers"]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "abc_123_ghi"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "dangdarn"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "oops32"
    **[3]=>
    string(8) "poss_dup"
    [4]=>
    string(10) "poss_dup_1"**
    [5]=>
    string(9) "pos_s_dup"
    **[6]=>
    string(13) "bad_chars_3_9"**
  }
  ["header_test"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["abc_123_ghi"]=>
    int(1)
    ["dangdarn"]=>
    int(1)
    ["oops32"]=>
    int(1)
    ["poss_dup"]=>
    int(2)
    ["pos_s_dup"]=>
    int(1)
    ["bad_chars_3_9"]=>
    int(1)
  }
```

VolkerK came up with the solution. Besides his other good suggestions, the key thing was unsetting $header after the foreach loop.

Comment: I guess you can't **bold** code, but that's what I was trying to do with the ******asterisks******

Comment: Yeah I run a function there. I'll add it into the question but I don't see how it would affect anything because it just uses some regex to clean the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just taking your code

```
<?php
$headers = array('Abc 123 ghi',
            'dangdarn',
            'oops32',
            'poss dup',
            'poss dup',
            'pos  _s_ dup',
            'bad chars\'& 3% 9'
           );

$header_test = array();
foreach($headers as &$header) { //passing by reference
    $temp = $header;
    if(array_key_exists($temp,$header_test)) {

        $header = $header . '_' . $header_test[$header];
        $header_test[$temp]++; 
        unset($temp);
    } else {
        $header_test[$temp] = 1;
    }
}

var_dump($headers);
```

produces

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "Abc 123 ghi"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "dangdarn"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "oops32"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "poss dup"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "poss dup_1"
  [5]=>
  string(12) "pos  _s_ dup"
  [6]=>
  &string(16) "bad chars'& 3% 9"
}
```

on my machine using php 5.3.5/win32. Looks like your "real" code does something else to $header in and/or after the loop.

A bit simplified (eliminating $tmp):

```
<?php
$headers = getData();
$header_test = array();
foreach($headers as &$header) { //passing by reference
    if( array_key_exists($header, $header_test) ) {
        $header = $header . '_' . $header_test[$header]++;
    }
    else {
        $header_test[$header] = 1;
    }
}

// removes the reference that's causing the & in front
// of the last element of $headers in the output of var_dump
// if $headers can be empty you need to guard this
// to avoid "undefined variable 'header' warning.
// Probably better to put this code in a function
// so that $header can fall out of scope automagically
unset($header); 

var_dump($headers);

function getData() {
    return array('Abc 123 ghi',
        'dangdarn',
        'oops32',
        'poss dup',
        'poss dup',
        'pos  _s_ dup',
        'bad chars\'& 3% 9',
        'poss dup',
        'poss dup'
    );
}
```

prints

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "Abc 123 ghi"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "dangdarn"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "oops32"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "poss dup"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "poss dup_1"
  [5]=>
  string(12) "pos  _s_ dup"
  [6]=>
  string(16) "bad chars'& 3% 9"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "poss dup_2"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "poss dup_3"
}
```

Comment: Thanks actually it looks like unset($header) had the desired result. Without it, I ended up with that duplicate value with the reference in front of it, and with it it immediately changes to the correct last value in the array. This is strange behavior, isn't it? I'll definitely end up putting this into a function. Thanks also for your good suggestions for the foreach loop. I actually only introduced the $temp variable for testing this bug. Thankfully I can get rid of it now. Thanks!

Answer (score -5):

It should be

```
foreach(&$headers as $header) { //passing by reference
```

&headers is the reference to the array and $header is a handle for each member. You could replace the handle with any identifier.

Comment: Yes, that is completely illegal. Refer to the PHP manual. I am doing it right, as far as putting & before $header and not $headers.